# How safe is updating the Windows registry in C#?

Tags: c#, windows, registry

I am writing a program that I want to include a free 30-day trial. I looked around at posts on this site and decided to have the program keep the expiry date in the Windows registry (rather than the Installer updating the registry). After adding a key and a value to HKLM hive, then deleting it through regedit, I managed to mess up an FTP Program that now errors out unless I say to run it as an administrator. It gives me an error suggesting that the user-specific info for this program is not configured correctly. I believe I corrupted the registry to cause this.

Two questions: If all I want to do it to add a key and some values to a customer's registry, what's my risk of causing problems on their machine?

Also, I was using RegisrtyKey.CreateSubKey with the RegistryOptions.Volatile option. I read that this just updates memory, not the registry files. I saw this as a good way to test my features - set up subkeys and values that will only be around until I reboot my machine. When I get the desired behavior from the code, switch it over to RegisrtyOptions.None. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Include something unique in your registry key path, like your domain name, to prevent collisions.  Don't rely on the name of your product to be unique.

Comment: Yep, I included my fictitious company name, but even the product names are quite different.

Comment: Would like to hear more about that Volatile option, if anyone has experience with it...thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing *per se* unsafe about updating the registry in C#, at least not moreso than any other language. If you are not touching a key that another program uses, you can do whatever you want.

I would suggest that if you had a problem, it is merely a coincidence that it happened around the same time you were editing the registry.

Comment: Well, the words are re-assuring. I also simplified what all I did editing the registry - I was trying to get the key into multiple hives, the local machine, users and current user. Ran into permission problems along the way. But I don't think I did anything to the registry of this program.